# OpenMP: how to make for loop distribution depend only on array size?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

Consider the following chunk of code:

```
int array[30000]

#pragma omp parallel
{
   for( int a = 0; a < 1000; a++ )
   {
       #pragma omp for nowait
       for( int i = 0; i < 30000; i++ )
       {
           /*calculations with array[i] and also other array entries happen here*/
       }
   }
}
```

Race conditions are not a concern in my application but I would like to enforce that each thread in the parallel regions takes care of **exactly** the same chunk of *array* at each run through the inner for loop.

It is my understanding that *schedule(static)* distributes the for-loop items based on the number of threads and the array length. However, it is not clear whether the distribution changes for different loops or different repetitions of the same loop (even when number of threads and length are the same).

What does the standard say about this? Is *schedule(static)* sufficient to enforce this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this quote from [OpenMP Specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu41.html#x64-1290002.9.2) provides such a guarantee:

> A compliant implementation of the **`static` schedule** must ensure that the **same assignment of logical iteration numbers to threads will be used in two worksharing-loop regions** if the following conditions are satisfied: 1) both worksharing-loop regions have the **same number of loop iterations**, 2) both worksharing-loop regions have the **same value of chunk_size specified**, **or** both worksharing-loop regions have **no chunk_size specified**, 3) both worksharing-loop regions bind to the **same parallel region**, and 4) neither loop is associated with a SIMD construct.